# VBA folder path based on user

Tags: excel, vba

I would need to open a file located in the Desktop with VBA. The thing is that the users change and so does the path (eg, C:\Users**user1111**\Desktop, C:\Users**user2222**\Desktop, C:\Users**user333**\Desktop, C:\Users**user4444**\Desktop, etc.).

If I include this Username in cell C1, how should I do to open it? This is the idea i came up with but i am not sure if it would be correct:

```
folder_path = "C:\Users\"
my_files = Dir(folder_path & "\Desktop\US - Dec.docx")

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(folder_path & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value & "\" & my_files)
```

Thank you

Comment: No need for that. Use `Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"`. Or `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")`.